# Can't get access tokens from twitter to access my account in android

Tags: android, twitter, token

I am using twitter api in my android app to make tweets from app on my account
But there are some errors i can't identify it when get access token after redirecting from twitterb..

I wish you can help me

this is my code

```
if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                            Toast.makeText(QuoteDialogActivity.this, "token get", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
                            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                                // oAuth verifier
                                final String verifier = uri
                                        .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                                try {

                                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            try {

                                                // Get the access token
                                                QuoteDialogActivity.this.accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                                                        requestToken,verifier);

                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    thread.start();

                                    // Shared Preferences
                                    Editor e = mPrefs.edit();

                                    // After getting access token, access token secret
                                    // store them in application preferences
                                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                                            accessToken.getToken());
                                    // Store login status - true
                                    e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                                    e.commit(); // save changes

                                    Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());


                                    // Getting user details from twitter
                                    // For now i am getting his name only
                                    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                                    User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                                    String username = user.getName();

                                    // Displaying in xml ui
//                                  lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username + "</b>"));
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    // Check log for login errors
                                    Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

==================================================

```
private void loginToTwitter() {
           // Check if already logged in
           if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
               ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
               builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
               builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
               Configuration configuration = builder.build();

               TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
               twitter = factory.getInstance();


                   Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           try {

                               requestToken = twitter
                                       .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                               QuoteDialogActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                       .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));

                           } catch (Exception e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                       }
                   });
                   thread.start();         
           } else {
               // user already logged into twitter
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       }


     private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
           // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
           return mPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
       }
```

====================================================

**logcat**

```
11-24 10:32:29.104: E/Twitter Login Error(3867): > null
11-24 10:32:29.104: W/System.err(3867): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-24 10:32:29.104: W/System.err(3867):     at com.engahmedphp.successquotes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:143)
11-24 10:32:29.104: W/System.err(3867):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-24 10:32:29.104: W/System.err(3867):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
11-24 10:32:29.104: W/System.err(3867):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
11-24 10:32:29.104: W/System.err(3867):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
11-24 10:32:29.104: W/System.err(3867):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
11-24 10:32:29.104: W/System.err(3867):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 10:32:29.104: W/System.err(3867):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-24 10:32:29.114: W/System.err(3867):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
11-24 10:32:29.114: W/System.err(3867):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 10:32:29.114: W/System.err(3867):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-24 10:32:29.114: W/System.err(3867):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-24 10:32:29.114: W/System.err(3867):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-24 10:32:29.114: W/System.err(3867):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 10:32:29.114: W/System.err(3867): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
11-24 10:32:29.114: W/System.err(3867):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
11-24 10:32:29.114: W/System.err(3867):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
11-24 10:32:29.114: W/System.err(3867):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
11-24 10:32:29.114: W/System.err(3867):     at com.engahmedphp.successquotes.MainActivity$5.run(MainActivity.java:126)
11-24 10:32:29.114: W/System.err(3867):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do on line 143 of MainActivity ? Inside your onCreate method ?

Comment: this line e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());

Comment: e maybe null or access token may be null. You should show that code and indicate clearly which line appear in the stack trace.

Comment: yes it returns with null but why ?

Comment: As this is your code, you are in a far better position to answer that question..

Comment: what can i do so ?? i am very frustrated and i spent huge time to search it

Comment: Debug you app, trace everything, find out why that value is null. Where should it be initialized to something different, what happens. All those are questions you should ask yourself. Test, probe, emit hypothesis. *You* can understand what's going wrong, a computer can only go wrong in that case, humans are so superior to machines :)